# How this String split()[1] method work

Tags: c#

I look at the `String.Split()` method in MSDN which is different from the above. can someone help to explain how this  works?

```
string boundary = resp.Headers["Content-Type"].Split('=')[1];
```

What is that `[1]`  beside the `.Split('=')[1]` means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String.Split` returns an array.

Writing `x[1]`, where `x` is an array, gets the 2<sup>nd</sup> element in the array.

Comment: Can this be called method chaining?

Comment: @Ran: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @Ran - Method chaining is usually something that is referred to when the method that is called on the object returns the same object as the result, so that you can 'chain' calls together on the same object. This is just drilling down the object hierarchy that is returned from the methods.

Comment: ThankQ. The syntax is abit confusion. But after you explain, it get clearer. Thanks

Comment: @Tejs: Thanx! So this is method chaining as well, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

```
string dir = "Saina*is*good girl";
string parts = dir.Split('*')[1].ToString();
Console.Write(parts);
```

It will return 'is' as a answer